# uipageviewcontroller with search bar not showing up

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have an ios7 app that is using a page view controller to swipe through a series of pages.  I want to have a navigation bar and a tool bar above this.  Heres a picture of what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddgXY.png

I have 3 views going to build this.

1. **Root** - a view controller embedded in a navigation grontroller
2. **Page View Controller** - a page view controller
3. **Page** - a view controller that represents the page (aka the big white box)

The **root** and **page** views are both subclassed from UIViewController

The search bar is in the **root** with the rest of the top navigation.  The navigation bar is fine (the menu button works) but I can't get the search bar to work.  It seems like the search bar is covered by either the **page view controller** or the **page**.  This is because it is only visible when I make the **page** background transparent (and if I bump up the space between pages, you can see it peaking thru between them as you swipe).  Even if I make the **page** background transparent, the taps don't make it thru and the keyboard never comes up.

I need a way to get this search bar to be visable and usable.  I don't want to put it in the page view because then it looks bad as you swipe thru the pages, like each page has one.  I want it sticky like the red navigation bar.

also, I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the search bar in the navigation bar instead of the title. Just drag the search bar to the title of the navigation bar